# How can i take last inserted PK computed varchar(7) field as output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output, scope-identity

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Admin_Profile](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ad_Regid]  AS ('R'+right('200'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID],(0)),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Ad_Fname] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Ad_Lname] [varchar](25) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Admin_Profile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ad_Regid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SP:

```
create procedure _insertAdminProfile
(
    @Ad_Fname varchar(25),
    @Ad_Lname varchar(25),
    @Ad_Pwd varchar(7) Out
    as 

    Begin

    insert into dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname,Ad_Lname) values (@Ad_Fname,@Ad_Lname);

    SELECT ISNULL(MAX(@Ad_Pwd), 0) + 1 FROM dbo.Admin_Profile

    end
```

I tried many ways to get the output of inserted.Ad_Regid...Not getting, I tried select `@Ad_Regid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` too.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this three variants to the your choice -

1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _insertAdminProfile
(
     @Ad_Fname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Lname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Pwd VARCHAR(7) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

     INSERT INTO dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname, Ad_Lname)
     VALUES (@Ad_Fname, @Ad_Lname)

     SELECT @Ad_Pwd = [Ad_Regid]
     FROM dbo.Admin_Profile
     WHERE [ID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _insertAdminProfile
(
     @Ad_Fname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Lname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Pwd VARCHAR(7) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

     INSERT INTO dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname, Ad_Lname)
     VALUES (@Ad_Fname, @Ad_Lname)

     SELECT @Ad_Pwd = 'R' + RIGHT('200'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SCOPE_IDENTITY(),0), 6)

END
```

3:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _insertAdminProfile
(
     @Ad_Fname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Lname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Pwd VARCHAR(7) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

     DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (Ad_Pwd VARCHAR(7));

     INSERT INTO dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname, Ad_Lname)
     OUTPUT INSERTED.Ad_Regid INTO @MyTableVar
     VALUES (@Ad_Fname, @Ad_Lname)

     SELECT @Ad_Pwd = Ad_Pwd
     FROM @MyTableVar

END
```

Comment: i want to return the field computed varchar field...not identity(int)...it seems it returns the integer value....

Comment: i Think the second one is perfect...I'll try it...Thank you once again Sir!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
DECLARE @OutputValues TABLE (ID INT, RegID VARCHAR(7))

INSERT INTO dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname, Ad_Lname) 
OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.Ad_RegId INTO @OutputValues(ID, RegID)
VALUES(@Ad_Fname, @Ad_Lname);
```

Once your insert statement has run, you'll have all inserted `ID` and corresponding `Ad_RegId` values inside your table variable `@OutputValues`

```
SELECT ID, RegID FROM @OutputValues
```

Read more about the [`OUTPUT` clause on SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the global varaibale @@IDENTITY?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _insertAdminProfile
(
     @Ad_Fname VARCHAR(25),
     @Ad_Lname VARCHAR(25),
     @ident NUMERIC OUT
)
AS BEGIN

     INSERT INTO dbo.Admin_Profile (Ad_Fname, Ad_Lname)
     VALUES (@Ad_Fname, @Ad_Lname);

     SET @ident = @@IDENTITY;

END
```

Comment: can return the value for computed varchar filed?

Comment: @Sugu, i very strongly doubt it. `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` almost are equal.

Comment: Please post the create script for the table. Then I may be able to help with that.